# How do you create an editable story in python?

Tags: python, anaconda, python-3.6

Hello I am looking to get the basics of replacing words in a story in python.
So far I have the code below. I am running spyder.

## Collect name from the user

## story about user

```
def Travsnguard():
    print ("Welcome to Travsngaurd!")
    
    #relative = input("Enter a type of relative.")
    name = input("Enter a name")
    #verb = input("Enter an 'ing' verb" )
    #adjective = input("Enter an adjective")
    #noun = input("Enter a noun")
    print ("Hello,", name, "your journey starts now!")
    enter code here
```

My program just runs and doesn't do anything else.

Comment: really stupid question, but you did call `Travsnguard()` at the end of your code, right?

Answer (score 1):

This is called string concatenation. You can just use the '+' symbol in this case.

```
name = input("What is your name?")
print("Hi, " + name + " nice to meet you."
```

In more complex cases you may wish to perform string interpolation - which is taking a fixed string and inserting values, like so:

```
name = input("What is your name?")
birthsign = input("What is your birthsign?")
race = input("What is your race?")
father = input("Who was your father?")

#%s = insert string - we then pass the variables to insert in order of use
storyString = "Welcome %s son of %s of the sign %s and race %s. You have travelled far." % (name, father, birthsign, race)

print(storyString)
```

Comment: Wow, you guys are wicked fast at responding thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I switched to raw inputs to ensure we get strings and then just concatenated the results into a string at the end. Is something like this what you are trying to do?

```
def Travsnguard():
    print ("Welcome to Travsngaurd!")
    relative = input("Enter a type of relative: ")
    name = input("Enter a name: ")
    verb = input("Enter an 'ing' verb: " )
    adjective = input("Enter an adjective: ")
    noun = input("Enter a noun: ")
    print ("Hello,", name, "your journey starts now!")
    print ("You are here with your " + adjective + " " + relative + " raul. and you\
are going to go " + verb + ". You are going to use your " + noun + ".")
Travsnguard()
```

Comment: `raw_input` isn't defined in python 3 (note that the question is tagged python 3.6)

Comment: Well that's embarassing, Thank you.

Comment: This helped a lot but the raw_input() function I don't think I can use on 3.6 it only lets me use the input() function. I did get it to look better now.

Comment: I edited to just use plain input, I need to switch to python three so I don't have these problems.

Comment: def Travsnguard():
    print ("Welcome to Travsngaurd!")
    relative = input("Enter a type of relative: ")
    name = input("Enter a name: ")
    verb = input("Enter an 'ing' verb: " )
    adjective = input("Enter an adjective: ")
    noun = input("Enter a noun: ")
    print ("Hello,", name, "your journey starts now!")
    print ("You are here with your " + adjective + " " + relative + " " + "and you\
 are going to go " + verb + ". You are going to use your " + noun + ".")
Travsnguard()